# How can I tell if a Windows 10 PC has the Anniversary Update installed?

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-v1607

Given a PC with Windows 10, how can I tell whether it has the Anniversary Update installed or not?

Comment: Check your update history, or run "winver", and provide us the information displayed

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `winver` and press ENTER

If the version number reads `1607`, then you have the Anniversary Update installed.

Comment: Thanks! I assume a number greater than 1607 means it has the Anniversary Update plus some future update(s).

Comment: Yes. That's correct. Likewise `1511` is November update. And the Build number will tell you which cumulative update has been installed.

Comment: Current build, of version 1607, as of today is .10

Comment: Anniversary Update and Redstone 1 update are the same or different?

Comment: `Anniversary Update` and `Redstone 1` are one and the same.

Comment: But shouldn't .NET 4.6.2 be installed automatically with it? The latest I have is 4.6.1 and is installed somewhere in march.

Comment: Creators Update or "Redstone 2" is 1703. The first two digits is the year (2017) and the second two the month (March) when the final build was made. The versions are listed on [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history).

Comment: How do you figure this out in 2023? I have 22H2 -- I have no idea what their numbering scheme is though. Where would I find that?

Answer (score 5):

You can determine this by looking at the Start menu, since the Anniversary Update changed it. Before the update, it looked like this (with words):

[image: old style]

After the update, it looks like this (just icons):

[image: new style]

A particularly salient difference is that the user avatar/name no longer appear at the top; rather, the avatar is above the File Explorer icon.